# Design Suggestion - JSON parsing and processing of MSSQL DB records

Tags: java, json, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am writing a framework which needs to fetch large number of records from a MSSQL DB and each record/row has a JSON data which I need to parse and then do some computation out of that JSON data. Parsing and computation of each record is independent. So looking for some design suggestions for this framework.

Below are some details.

- Language : Java
- No of DB records : pretty large so would need some kind of batching
  and parallel processing.
- Libraries currently thinking of to use : GSON (any other suggestion?)

-Thanks

Comment: If you want batch processing take a look at Spring Batch project.

Comment: Im seriously wondering why you would put JSON in a relational database.

Comment: @stealthjong my whole product doesn't put json widely in db, its just a small feature of it which polls for a table where some other product component dumps json data.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar project. These are some important lessons I learnt

1. **Parser library**: I moved from json-simple to json-smart. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/wiki/Benchmark) is a comparsion of various libraries. When reading from primary hard disk, the running time with json-
   smart was only 60% compared to that of json-simple
2. **Reusing objects**: Assuming you have large number of records to handle, re-use the same JSONObject for all records changing the values. NEVER initialize objects in a loop

Comment: Thanks Rishi, could you provide some more details on how you designed like did you read and parsed each DB record sequentially or did batch reading from DB first and then parsing or anything else.

Comment: In my case, I had to read sequentially as I was reading Terabytes of data. So I kept parsing records as I read them. What would work best for you would depend on your application, size of data, available resources etc.

Comment: Thanks Rishi, interested in knowing the kind of optimizations you did in your sequential approach specially in terms of db reads.

Comment: Didn't use SQL. Indexed my data in Apahce Lucene so my optimizations are Lucene Specific. Btw remember to upvote and accept answers that help you.

Comment: Thanks Rishi, yes I will.